# How to hide clicked element and show different element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a button displayed below. When I click it should hide and another background image should come.

[image]

I am adding this from backed displayed below

```
htmlDataId += "<a onclick=\"getChilds('"+row[primaryField]+"','false','UniqueId')\" title='View' ><i class='plus-symbol' style='height:2px;' id="+row['Id']+"> </i></a>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp${row[selectedLabel]}"
```

On click only symbol should hide with jquery function and replace with other background image.

This method will get execute onclick

```
function getChilds(primaryId, isFlat, col) {
        alert(event.target.id);
        //$("#'+ event.target.id +'").removeClass('plus-symbol')
        alert(primaryId)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest switching class when appropriate, instead of hiding/showing elements.

You can use `hideClass` and `removeClass` from [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) (which you tagged in the question), something like:

```
htmlDataId += "<a onclick=\"$(this).find('i').removeClass('plus-symbol').addClass('minus-symbol')\" title='View' ><i class='plus-symbol' style='height:2px;' id="+row['Id']+"> </i></a>"
```

Comment: I have assigned id for that can I use id to remove class and add class coz I have id as unique

Comment: And the commented line with the `removeClass` doesn't work?

Comment: @SohamShetty Oh, because it removes the class from the `a`, you can use the `find('i')` there

Comment: Where and what is "I" and I have not added your html which you suggested in answer

Comment: @SohamShetty the `i` is from `<i class='plus-symbol'...`